# API para pegar imagem de um buscador

Tags: api

Terei que adicionar uma função no site que estou trabalhando de que o usuário irá pesquisar por nome imagens em algum buscador  da Web (este pode ser Google, Yahoo, Bing e etc.) e as imagens encontradas serão listadas em uma div na qual ele poderá seleciona-la e ela poderá ser usada.

Existe alguma API ou jeito para se fazer isso? Eu pesquisei na internet mas não encontrei nada semelhante até o momento. E aliás, pode-se fazer isso sem problema algum?

Answer (score 2):

É possível sim, por exemplo um bom provedor para imagens é o Bing. Ele oferece uma API, que é paga, mas dependendo do uso, o custo pode valer a pena, por exemplo 1000 pesquisas por 3 dolares por mês. Seguem as documentações de exemplo e referências:

[Documentação e exemplos](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/cognitive-services/bing-image-search/search-the-web)

[Assistente para Visual Studio](http://www.bing.com/partners/tools#DevAssistant)

[Bing Image Search API](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/cognitive-services/bing-image-search-api/)

[Lista de Preços para consumo da API](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/pricing/details/cognitive-services/search-api/image/)

[Bing search API - Outras possibilidades de pesquisa além de imagens](http://www.bing.com/partners/developers#BingSearchApi)